# Inheriting rails_admin properties

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I have several models that inherit from a `Content` class;

```
class Article < Content
class Magazine < Content
...
```

Currently if in `Article` I want to give my rails_admin access to a specific property I need to duplicate all the properties as I can't find a way to add properties into the rails_admin block;

```
class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
  rails_admin do
    field: title
    field: body
  end
end

class Article < Content
   rails_admin do
     field: title
     field: body
     field: unqiue_article_field
   end
end
```

This feels clunky – is there a better approach?

I did try creating modules that contained blocks of fields/properties but again they were simply overriding what was there.

Comment: Modules are usually the way to go with this sort of thing.  I don't understand quite what you are trying to do with the `rails_admin` call.

Comment: With the rails_admin gem this is how you tell rails_admin which fields to present in the back end.

Comment: If you are calling rails_admin with different options in different classes, i don't see how you could clean it up any further.  Potentially, if they all used `:title` and `:body` you could have some module storing those as defaults and passing them through, but it's a lot of hassle and it would make your code much more complex than it needs to be.  From a readability/comprehensibility point of view what you are doing already seems fine to me.

Comment: You stumble upon one of the rails admins weaknesses, you can't easily reuse configuration, sorry :(